# Vue.js - How do you bind a checkbox to an array in a v-for

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm trying to see if I can pass an array of data from one component to another to essentially bulk update the selected rows via a database, I know that props are read only. The issue I'm facing is when I want to select the data from the parent component using a checkbox, it seems to not recognise the ID/value of the selected row, which in this instance when console logging the array they all come back as `[ "row.id" ]` and because of this, all the checkboxes on the table are checked. Code sample below:

```
<tr v-for="row in data" :key="row.id" class="data">
 <td>
  <input type="checkbox" id="row.id" v-model="selectedRows" value="row.id">
 </td>
...
</tr>
```

I've tried using `row[key]` in place of `row.id` but doesn't seem to have changed anything, is there a Vue function that allows this process to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You did not bind the `row.id` to `input`. That's why it taking value as `row.id`.

Do like this:

`<input type="checkbox" :id="row.id" v-model="selectedRows" :value="row.id">`

If you want to check the another way of doing the same, you can check out this [link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue-zvsycd).